# Equivalent of interlinear for audio?

Tags: learning-methods, resource-request, english, multiple-languages

I'm interested in learning a foreign language by audiobook format where the sentence is read once in English, then a second time in the foreign language.

Does this have a name?

Do any resources like this exist?